# Deviceorientaion event isn't working on Chrome on Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, dom-events, device-orientation

So basically, the `deviceorientation` event, when the page is running on Android Chrome, doesn't seem to work. The event handler function is never called.

Now the weird thing is that when the same code is run on a Chrome browser on a computer and device orientation is virtually simulated through the Chrome dev tools (*Dev tools/More tools/Sensors/Orientation*), everything works perfectly fine.

I thought at first, that maybe my phone doesn't have a gyroscope or doesn't support `deviceorientation`, but I can watch 360° videos on YouTube with it for instance. And I have tried many demos for `deviceorientation`, and all of them work (including [this one (threejs.org)](https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html) and [this other one](https://www.audero.it/demo/device-orientation-api-demo.html) for example).

Now all of these demos worked both when simulated with the dev tools, and when ran on my Android phone, but there is one exception though. The [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/WebAPI/Detecting_device_orientation) documentation/demo for `deviceorientation`, only works when simulated through dev tools, and not on my phone - exactly what happens with my code...

I don't understand how `deviceorientation` seems to work in some cases on Chrome Android, but in some other cases - including with my code and Mozilla's code -, doesn't...

Any help or any remarks would help a lot!

**PS**: If it has anything to say, here is the code I use to detect the device's orientation. It's basically a copy-paste from Mozilla's website:

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function (event) {
    var absolute = event.absolute;
    var alpha = event.alpha;
    var beta = event.beta;
    var gamma = event.gamma;
                
    console.log(alpha);
}, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is really stupid! If anyone happens to be stuck as I was with this problem, here is what I found at, and how I solved it:

It might be a bug, or it might be a feature, but `deviceorientation` doesn't seem to work on Android Google Chrome when it is loaded from a local file? When opened, Chrome doesn't open the file itself - if you look at the URL when opened, it isn't *C://Android/ETC/file.html* or something like on a computer as you might expect it to be, but *content://media/external/file/435765* or something similar. I don't why it is done this way, but it must be for a reason I suppose.

Well, **I THINK** that is what causes the problem, and therefore, following that logic, having the code on a web server might solve the problem.

Luckily for me, in my case, my `deviceorientation` problem is only a part of something that already needs web deployment. Therefore, I just deployed my code to the worldwide web, and to my surprise, my code now worked!

The fact that it doesn't work when run locally is just stupid! As you can see, on this table from [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DeviceOrientationEvent), `deviceorientation` should be compatible with Chrome on Android, which it is, just not when run locally for some reason:

[image: deviceorientation compatibilty]

Comment: I have deployed to EC2 and serving with HTTPS and it is still not working.